# How to change text inside a div

Tags: javascript

There are elements in a dynamically generated webpage that look like this:

```html
<div class="Lore Ipsum">foo bar</div>  
<div class="Lore Ipsum">ham spam</div>
```

I want to see some notes after text like following:

```
foo bar - Wrong  
ham spam - Right
```

How can I get those elements and add comments?
Thanks in advance.

Note: I am not the author of the page mentioned above, so I cannot edit sources.

Comment: What determines whether something is 'Wrong' or 'Right' ?

Answer (score 3):

Here's one approach:

```
​var divs = document.getElementsByTagName('div');

for (var i=0, len=divs.length; i<len; i++){
    var current = divs[i];
    if (current.className == 'Lore Ipsum') {
        switch (current.firstChild.nodeValue) {
            case 'foo bar':
                current.firstChild.nodeValue += '- wrong';
                break;
            case 'ham spam':
                current.firstChild.nodeValue += '- right';
                break;
        }
    }
}​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/3r3bj/).

This approach is, however, based on a couple of assumptions that I had to make due to the lack of specifics in the question, and the HTML as written. Those assumptions are:

1. That you only want to check the text-content of those `div` elements with a class of *both* `Lore` *and* `Ipsum` (and that those class-names will *always* be in that order),
2. and that the text you want to check will always be the `firstChild` of the `div` elements you want to check.

---

The above code revised to make the order of the class-names unimportant:

```
var divs = document.getElementsByTagName('div');

for (var i=0, len=divs.length; i<len; i++){
    var current = divs[i],
        cName = current.className;
    if (cName.indexOf('Lore') > -1 && cName.indexOf('Ipsum') > -1) {
        switch (current.firstChild.nodeValue) {
            case 'foo bar':
                current.firstChild.nodeValue += ' - wrong';
                break;
            case 'ham spam':
                current.firstChild.nodeValue += ' - right';
                break;
        }
    }
}​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/3r3bj/1/).

Revised again, in response to Shadow Wizard's accurate comment (below the answer):

> It won't work if there is whitespace in the div contents. [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/3r3bj/2/) - maybe adding a function to retrieve the first non empty child?

Using `trim()` removes preceding and trailing white-space from the `nodeValue` for the purposes of comparison, so `foo bar` should now equal `foo bar`:

```
var divs = document.getElementsByTagName('div');

for (var i=0, len=divs.length; i<len; i++){
    var current = divs[i],
        cName = current.className;
    if (cName.indexOf('Lore') > -1 && cName.indexOf('Ipsum') > -1) {
        switch (current.firstChild.nodeValue.trim()) {
            case 'foo bar':
                current.firstChild.nodeValue += ' - wrong';
                break;
            case 'ham spam':
                current.firstChild.nodeValue += ' - right';
                break;
        }
    }
}​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/3r3bj/3/).

References:

- [`getElementsByTagName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.getElementsByTagName).
- [`node.firstChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.firstChild).
- [`node.nodeValue`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.nodeValue).
- [`switch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch).
- [`trim()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim).

Comment: It won't work if there is whitespace in the div contents. [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/3r3bj/2/) - maybe adding a function to retrieve the first non empty child?

Comment: @ShadowWizard: I probably *should* go to a full-on DRY solution, but I thought I'd leave that as an exercise for the OP. In the meantime, though, here's [`trim()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim), which addresses the preceding/trailing white-space problem. Though now I'm not sure I shouldn't go for an `indexOF()`, or regex, solution, but without specifics in the question it's difficult to know exactly what's happening, or what the criteria might be.

Comment: Agreed, as far as we know he can also have `<div class="Lore Ipsum"><b>foo</b> <u>bar</u></div>` so maybe `innerText` is what's needed.. can't really tell without more details from OP.

Comment: Or, indeed, a whole host of *other* alternatives. Oh, specifics: *I miss you*.

Answer (score 2):

Got rid of the ID concept. That's way too unmaintainable.

```
​<div class="lore">Foo Bar</div>
<div class="lore">Ham Spam</div>
<div class="lore">Pina Colada</div>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

Javascript

```
​​var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("lore");
for(i=0;i<=elements.length;i++) {
    content = elements[i].innerHTML;
    switch(content) {
        case "Foo Bar" :
            elements[i].innerHTML = content+ " - Wrong";
            break;
        case "Ham Spam" :
            elements[i].innerHTML = content + " - Right";
            break;
        default : 
            elements[i].innerHTML = content + " - What?";
    }            
}
```

To use getElementsByClassName in more antiquated browsers like older versions of IE...actually only IE, you can always use the Robert Nyman approach

http://robertnyman.com/2008/05/27/the-ultimate-getelementsbyclassname-anno-2008/

I also noticed it was mentioned this was dynamic content, which means it may come after the onLoad event is called.

If this is the case, make it all into a function and then use an HTML component like a button or anchor tag to call that function

HTML

```
<div class="lore">Foo Bar</div>
<div class="lore">Ham Spam</div>
<div class="lore">Pina Colada</div>

<button onclick="validate()">Validate</button>
```

JavaScript

```
window.validate = function() {
    var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("lore");
    for (i = 0; i <= elements.length; i++) {
        content = elements[i].innerHTML;
        switch (content) {
        case "Foo Bar":
            elements[i].innerHTML = content + " - Wrong";
            break;
        case "Ham Spam":
            elements[i].innerHTML = content + " - Right";
            break;
        default:
            elements[i].innerHTML = content + " - What?";
        }
    }
}
```

​

http://jsfiddle.net/S5VBh/1/

Comment: it's relative. What if in the future s/he wants <span class="wrong">Wrong</span>. You can't think about the now. Web pages are supposed to be responsive, not unmaintainable

Comment: look title~ "How to change text inside a div"

Comment: @HackerWins If you plan to use `innerText`, then you must also consider `textContent`. Different browsers have different implementations of this function.

Comment: @HackerWins - the "comments" in the question are a different colour, so I'd be using a span for that as per Christopher's suggestion for the future. Which in turn means `innerHTML` is the simplest solution...

Comment: @nnnnnn "I"? Are you the OP? Did you create a new account to ask this question, or am I missing something?

Comment: @PPvG - Seriously? No I'm not the OP. In my previous comment I said "I'd" as in "I would" as in "I would do it that way if it were my code". (I didn't say "I'll" as in "I will" as in "I will do it".)

Comment: @all agree. but "your vote is now locked in unless this answer is edited" sorry

Comment: @nnnnnn: Oh, I see. I was confused by "the comments in question are a different colour" - I thought you knew more than the question said, but I now realise you were referring to SO's automatic syntax hilights. My apologies. :)

Comment: getElementsByClassName for IE?

Comment: @HackerWins I added a link for the OP. If he wants to implement getElementsByClassName he can scope the code written by Robert Nyman.

Answer (score 1):

IF you are looking to add different HTML based on HTML content then you can loop through the elements and search each element's innerHTML and modify accordingly.

```
var els = document.getElementsByClassName("Lore Ipsum");
for(var i in els)
{
    switch(els[i].innerHTML){
        case "foo bar":
els[i].innerHTML = els[i].innerHTML + " - Wrong";
 break;
 case "ham spam":
els[i].innerHTML = els[i].innerHTML + " - Right";
 break;            
    };

}​
```

See this live example.

http://jsfiddle.net/MgUJK/

Comment: 'getElementsByClassName' for IE?

Comment: @Reimeus added the code.  :)  I like the live execution on jsFiddle.

Comment: @HackerWins Good point!  I was just showing an example of approach.  David Thomas's answer has better browser support.

Answer (score 0):

with jquery

```
$('#idname').html( 'some text' );
```

Comment: The OP did not ask for jQuery.

Comment: @David: The OP? did not specify the environment :)

Comment: @wkaha It's implicit that the OP isn't asking for a library solution since the question isn't tagged with jQuery, he isn't using jQuery in his question, and by the simplicity of the question that's being asked. Don't use a jQuery solution unless the OP is expecting a jQuery solution.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do the following:

1. Every **div** that you need to change the contents of, should have an ID. So you'd write the div tag like this:
2. Use simple Javascript and modify the contents like this example.

   document.getElementById('MyDiv').innerHTML = 'foo bar - wrong or whatever';

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [document.getElementsByClassName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.getElementsByClassName) to get the relevant elements and append some text to them. For example:

```html
<div class="lorem_ipsum">foo bar</div>  
<div class="lorem_ipsum">ham spam</div>
```

```js
var divs = document.getElementsByClassName('lorem_ipsum');

for (var i=0; i<divs.length; i++) {
    var content = divs[i].innerHTML;
    if (content == "foo bar")
        content += " - Wrong";
    else if (content == "ham spam")
        content += " - Right";

    divs[i].innerHTML = content;
}
```

Browser support for `getElementsByClassName` varies. Most modern browsers support it and return either a [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/NodeList) or an [HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/HTMLCollection). Both have a property `length` and expose their elements for use with bracket notation (`[]`).

To get full cross-browser compatibility, some tricks are required. In those cases where old browsers need to be supported, using a JavaScript framework (like [jQuery](http://jquery.com/)) is advisable.

Using jQuery, the above becomes trivial:

```
$('.lorem_ipsum').each(function() {
    content = $(this).text();
    if (content == "foo bar")
        content += " - Wrong";
    else if (content == "ham spam")
        content += " - Right";

    $(this).text(content);
});
```

Comment: You can use `document.querySelectorAll()` over gEBCN which works even in IE8 and also gives a static nodelist rather than a live one. All free advantages over gEBCN.